# Strange behavior of OpenCL atomic add operation

Tags: opencl, atomic, gpgpu

For a project, I had to dive into OpenCL: things are going fairly well except now that I need atomic operations.
I'm executing the OpenCL code on top of an Nvidia GPU, with the last drivers. `clGetDeviceInfo()` querying `CL_DEVICE_VERSION` returns me:
    `OpenCL 1.0 CUDA`, hence I guess I have to refer to the OpenCL 1.0 specs.

I started using an `atom_add` operation in my kernel on a `__global int* vnumber` buffer:
    `atom_add(&vnumber[0], 1);`. This gave me clearly wrong results. Thus, as an additional check, I have moved the add instruction at the beginning of the kernel, so that it is executed for each thread. When the kernel is launched with 512 x 512 threads, the content of `vnumber[0]` is: `524288`, which is exactly 2 x 512 x 512, two times the value that I should get. The funny thing is that by changing the add operation to `atom_add(&vnumber[0], 2);`, the returned value is `65536`, again two times what I should get.

Did someone already experienced something similar? Am I missing something very basic? I have checked the correctness of data types but it seems ok (I'm using `*int` buffer, and allocating it with `sizeof(cl_int)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using atom_add, which is an OpenCL 1.0 extension for local memory. Yet you are passing it global memory. Instead, try OpenCL 1.1's atomic_add, which works with global memory.

Comment: Querying my CL_DEVICE_VERSION returns OpenCL 1.0, hence I am referring to these specs: [link](http://r00tsecurity.org/db/cheat-sheets/Programming/OpenCL/opencl-quick-reference-card.pdf). Atomic are implemented as an extension, my GPU supports the extension "cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics" therefore I guess I can use atomics only on global memory buffers. Or, at least, also global memory. Moreover, can I use the atomic_add instruction if only version 1.0 seems to be supported?

Comment: The difference between atom_add and atomic_add is NOT that it works on global memory. There are the cl_khr_(global or local)_int(size)_(base or extended)_atomics, and then built in ones. You will need to enable the  global and/or local version for what you need. The atom_* ones are the extensions, and the atomic_ are the built in ones, and also require the pointer to be volatile.